# Method in Angular2 template binding

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm trying to return the category name as a string in a template of a component. The method is stored in the provider for the given data model.

For example:

```
     <div class="category">
            {{ vendorProvider.getCategoryName(vendor.category_id) }}
        </div>
```

And in the provider:

```
  getCategoryName(id) {
        return this.vendorCategories.find((x => x.id === id)).name;
    }
```

But I sometimes get errors such as 'Could not read property 'name' of undefined' when manipulating the vendor variable, say, in an edit form. What is the proper way to use a method in an Angular template binding? Or how else can I retrieve the category name from a array variable with a provided category ID?

Comment: Check your collection as `this.vendorCategories.find((x => x.id === id))` doesn't have any object for given id

Comment: @jitender The object is returned on the view, but the error still shows - while the vendor variable is loading from a HTTP get, the error occurs.

Comment: you have to show your full code for batter explanation

Comment: @Josh try my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just return the object from function and then use safe navigation operator in template

```
getCategoryName(id) {
     return this.vendorCategories.find((x => x.id === id));
}
```

in template

```
{{ vendorProvider.getCategoryName(vendor.category_id)?.name }}
```

Comment: Ty. God bless m8

Comment: @usee1533603 Actually the only problem with this is it doesn’t automatically update when the category id changes

Comment: How do you update category id? There is not much difference between your code and this solution. So if that works this should also work fine.

Comment: I update it literally by running this.vendor.category_id = X